# Load a Component in custom element dynamically

Tags: typescript, angular

I'm trying to inject a component on a container dinamically

**Component:**

```js
@Component({...})
export class InvestmentProcess{

    @ViewChild('container') container;
    constructor(public dcl: DynamicComponentLoader) {}

    loadComponent(fooComponent: Type){
        this.dcl.loadNextToLocation(fooComponent, container);
    }
}
```

**Template:**

```html
<div #container> </div>
```

When I run the function `loadComponent` the following error is thrown:

`TypeError: location.createComponent is not a function`

That's becouse `container` is an `ElementRef` typed variable, and `loadNextToLocation` expects a `ViewContainerRef` as the second parameter. As [official docs](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/ViewContainerRef-class.html) said, the `ViewContainerRef` can be extracted from an element via `@ViewChild`, but I haven't find any example to do it properly.

*Working with Angular2.0.0rc1*

Comment: *For a detailed how to with plunker check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37044960/1679310)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DynamicComponentLoader` is going to be deprecated. Use `ViewContainerRef.createComponent()`

```
@Component({...})
export class InvestmentProcess{

    @ViewChild('container', {read: ViewContainerRef}) container:ViewContainerRef;
    constructor(private resolver: ComponentResolver) {}

    loadComponent(fooComponent: Type){
      this.resolver.resolveComponent(fooComponent).then((factory:ComponentFactory<any>) => {
        this.cmpRef = this.target.createComponent(factory)
      });        
    }
}
```

See also [Angular 2 dynamic tabs with user-click chosen components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468)